# Work around for split function when last character is a terminator

Tags: perl, split

I have this line of data with 20 fields:

```
my $data = '54243|601|0|||0|N|0|0|0|0|0||||||99582|';
```

I'm using this to split the data:

```
my @data = split ('\|'), $data;
```

However, instead of 20 pieces of data, you only get 19:

```
print scalar @data;
```

I could manually `push` an empty string onto `@data` if the last character is a `|` but I'm wondering if there is a more perlish way.

Comment: Your input only has 18 `|` characters (so 18-19 data)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do

```
my @data = split /\|/, $data, -1;
```

The -1 tells [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to include empty trailing fields.

(Your parentheses around the regex are incorrect, and lead to $data not being considered a parameter of split.  Also, with one exception, the first argument of split is always a regex, so it is better to specify it as a regex not a string that will be interpreted as a regex.)